# Magento, indexer.php with exec in PHP, can not do reindex only reindexall

Tags: php, shell, magento, exec

When trying to run a reindex by php with exec, I can only execute the reindexall option but not the --reindex option. Whenever I try to use the -- I think it runs into an error and shows either no error or the help screen of the php-command. These are the lines I tried.

```
php -f '$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product'
```

Empty return

```
php -f $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
```

This shows the help screen of the php-command

```
php -f $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

This shows reindex successful but only for all indexes which might take some time.

```
echo $s = "php -f $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/shell/indexer.php reindexall";
echo "<br>";
echo exec($s,$o2,$r2); 
print_r($o2);
print_r($r2);
```

Comment: it looks like this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/31416/3359

Comment: "php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product "

This way it works. it was because of the -f option. Just removed it and it worked for only this index.